# NoMethod error in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am following a tutorial where we are creating and updating user accounts, and Im stuck on the edit part as when I try to load the edit page for a user I get a no method error as shown below:

```
Showing /home/ubuntu/rails_projects/alpha_blog/app/views/shared/_errors.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #1):
1
2
3
4
5
6

<% if obj.errors.any? %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
      <div class="panel panel-danger">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h2 class="panel-title">

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/users/_form.html.erb, app/views/users/edit.html.erb

Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/rails_projects/alpha_blog

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/shared/_errors.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__errors_html_erb__3874437342468649522_70028100096200'
app/views/users/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_users__form_html_erb__2653828291511096048_70028100213300'
app/views/users/edit.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_users_edit_html_erb___925607472456440074_70028151623400'
Request
Parameters:

{"id"=>"2"}
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
Response
Headers:

None
```

Here is my users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user= User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the alpha blog #{@user.username}"
      redirect_to articles_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end

  end

  private

  def user_params

    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password)
  end

  def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  end 

  def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Your account was updated successfully"
      redirect_to articles_path
    else

      render 'edit'
    end


  end




end
```

Since I initialized the variable @user in the edit class, I thought this would work.

Comment: Your `obj` is nil. Where did you expect it to come from? Should it be `@user`?

Answer (score 2):

In file _app/views/users/*form.html.erb*, while rendering _shared/*errors.html.erb* partial, also pass `obj` as local to it. This is how you can do it:

```
<%= render 'shared/errors', obj: @user %>
```

If it doesn't work, please post *users/edit* and *users/_form* templates too.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 answers to your question

1. If you are using "**Devise**" gem, try accessing it using "*resource.errors*" instead of obj.errors
2. If you are making your custom form, so basically in your **partial**, Object is not found. So from wherever this partial is rendering, you can try using the below code. So you are trying to access error for obj, which is a nil class. Try passing the locals as below

   > render(:partial => 'users/feeds', :locals => { :obj => @user })